# How can I send message to specific chatID?

Tags: telegram-bot

I have chatId and want send messages while execute some tasks from java code. I found this explain on telegram "Bots can't initiate conversations with users. A user must either add them to a group or send them a message first. People can use telegram.me/ links or username search to find your bot." But my task works good when I use https request directly from browser. My bot perfectly answer for requests but how I can do this without user request?

Comment: As your bot can reply successfully for user query, it should work for the purpose you mentioned. First you have to define when bot will send message, fire that sendMessage() method using chat_id (you got somehow) when you want to send.
In another word, just define another `endpoint` for sending message where `/sendMessage` will be called.

N.B.: user must add bot in their contact

Answer (score 0):

I can not truly understand your case! 
Anyway, your bot can send a message to a chat ID Only if the user witch blongs to the specified chat ID added your bot (send start to a bot).

and if it happened then send your message with

> /sendMessage